# Undefined numbers of rows when writing a title for ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to plot a dataset.
The dataset is like this:

```
    pr0   pr1
A1  0.1   0.9
A2  0.2   0.8
A3  0.7   0.3
```

Below is my code:

`aggregate <- function(){agg.1 <- data
                         rownames(agg.1) <- colnames(Q)
                         agg <- melt(agg.1)
                         per.agg <- paste(round(100*(agg.1[,2]), 2), "%", sep="")
                         text <- paste(per.agg[1],"have A1","\n",
                                       per.agg[2],"have A2","\n",
                                       per.agg[3],"have A3","\n")
                         ggplot(data=agg,aes(x=agg[,1], y=agg[,3],fill=factor(agg[,2])))+
                         geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "stack")+ 
                         xlab("")+ylab("Aggregated Examinee Attribute Mastery Rate")+
                         ggtitle(text)
}`

The problem is that the possible numbers in per.agg[_] may range from 1 to 100, and in "of examinees have mastered A1", "A1" could be from 1 to 100. Now I have listed three, but when I have four, for example,

```
    pr0   pr1
A1  0.1   0.9
A2  0.2   0.8
A3  0.7   0.3
A4  0.3   0.7
```

I will need to add per.agg[4], and A4. The number will be the same as ncol(Q). How can I incorporate every possible number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example which I think you could pretty quickly adapt to your situation:

#### generate some data

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5],
                  y = rpois(5,5))

df1

#   x y
# 1 a 4
# 2 b 7
# 3 c 4
# 4 d 8
# 5 e 9
```

#### use `sapply`, `paste`, and specify `collapse = ' \n '`

```
paste(sapply(1:nrow(df1), 
      function(x) paste(df1[x,2], 'have', paste0('A',x))), 
      collapse = ' \n ')

# "4 have A1 \n 7 have A2 \n 4 have A3 \n 8 have A4 \n 9 have A5"
```

For your example, I think you'd replace `1:nrow(df1)` with `1:ncol(Q)` and `df1[x,2]` with `per.agg[x]`:

```
paste(sapply(1:ncol(Q), 
      function(x) paste(per.agg[x], 'have', paste0('A',x))), 
      collapse = ' \n ')
```

Comment: Thank you! @bouncyball This works perfectly. I did not know the collapse function before this. Thanks a lot!